# How do I determine timestamp when each excel sheet is selected

Tags: excel, vba

My code I've written so far takes the username, computername and current datetime and writes it to a SQL table. What I want to do is capture when different sheets are selected and the timestamp associated with each.

```
Sub UpdateTable()

Dim cnn As ADODB.Connection
Dim uSQL As String
Dim strText As String
Dim strDate As Date
Dim strUsername As String
Dim strComputerName As Variant

strUsername = Environ("username")
strComputerName = Environ("Computername")
strDate = Now

Set cnn = New Connection
cnnstr = "Provider=SQLOLEDB; " & _
        "Data Source=icl-analive; " & _
        "Initial Catalog=DW_ALL;" & _
        "User ID=dw_all_readonlyuser;" & _
        "Trusted_Connection=Yes;"

cnn.Open cnnstr

uSQL = "INSERT INTO Audit (UN,CN,DT) VALUES ('" & strUsername & "','" &  strComputerName & "','" & strDate & "');" ''

Debug.Print uSQL

cnn.Execute uSQL
cnn.Close
Set cnn = Nothing
Exit Sub
End Sub
```

Comment: Do you need to run the same sql insertion in that sub or create a different record with that data in another table ?

Comment: The SQL inserts are all going to one table.

Comment: I know, what i mean is that if you need to run this same code everytime user clicks another sheet

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure if I'm oversimplifying this but from what I understand:

Add the `UpdateTable()` sub to a Module. Add a `Worksheet_Activate()` event to each worksheet you want to run `UpdateTable()`.

When the worksheet is selected the `UpdateTable()` sub will run, which will add the username, computer name and timestamp to your database. It may be worth adding the worksheet name (if you're looking to run this across multiple worksheets)

Therefore, when a worksheet is selected you could add the `Application.ActiveSheet.Name` and any other values (timestamp, user, etc) to the database.

Comment: Is there a way to add this to my existing code where the current worksheet open is inserted to my SQL table?

Comment: `Application.ActiveSheet.Name` returns the name of the current **active** worksheet. You could add a field to your database for the worksheet name and when your sub `UpdateTable()` is ran; insert `Application.ActiveSheet.Name`

Comment: I'm not too sure how peer reviewing works, however, I edited your question to show an example of the above. Every time the code is run the active worksheet is inserted into your database along with the username, computer name and timestamp.